# Linearizing If-Then condition

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

Somewhere in the internet, I have read that,

suppose, $x, y \in \mathbb{R}, ~and, ~~~ z \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$

$\text{if}~ x>y, ~\text{then,}~ z = 0 \implies \text{if}~ z = 1, ~ \text{then,}~ x \leq y$

It will be great if anyone has any reference to prove this fact.

P.S. I have lost the slide where I was introduced to this fact. And after a days search, I still did not manage to find that particular reference.

N.B. Please point to to correct forum, if I have asked to the wrong site.

Comment: Isn't this the contrapositive?

Comment: Yeah. Absolutely.

Comment: Use \text{if } to separate text from math symbols

Comment: The answer depends on whether or not it is a optimization problem.

Comment: That's true. I remember, they used big-M to obtain the linearization of the if-else statement.

Comment: See [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/05/indicator-constraints.html)

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Can you please check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839531/mip-equivalent-of-if-conditions)